# Display a tooltip for few seconds on click event in android

Tags: android, tooltip

I want to display some information using tool-tip for few seconds on click event of a view in android.

Comment: Would a Toast be enough? Then you could just use Toast.makeText(context, "Some information", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: No, I want to do it using a Tooltip. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Prior to Android O, there is no built-in support for tooltips in Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the following lib. It will help you for development.

[android-simple-tooltip](https://github.com/douglasjunior/android-simple-tooltip)

Answer (score 21):

you can do this by setting click listener to your view and inside onclicklistener, perform long click as in the code below

```
//Set Tooltip
TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(myTextView,"my tooltip")
//
myTextView.setOnClickListener{
    myTextView.performLongClick()
}
```

Comment: this is the thing that I want. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can place a textview below your button,
Than when user presses the button make it enable and disable using thread with getting current time adding the hint time you want till.
Bydefault android does not support this feature so you have make it work this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html,)

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

Or check [here](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/146) to tooltips arsenal.

Answer (score -1):

Starting from Android 8.0, can specify the tooltip text in a View by calling the `setTooltipText()` method. You can set the `tooltipText` property using the corresponding XML attribute or API.

The tooltip text appears near a view when users long press the view or hover their mouse over it.

**With XML:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:tooltipText="Send an email" />
```

**With Java:**

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setTooltipText("Send an email");
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/tooltips