# Extends SwitchMaterial and NPE happen

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

I am trying to customize `SwitchMaterial` class in Android, like this

```
class TipSwitchMaterial @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = android.R.attr.switchStyle
) : SwitchMaterial(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

}
```

I use `TipSwitchMaterial` in a activity xml like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    tools:context=".SidActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

...

        <com.omnieyes.omnilite.view.TipSwitchMaterial
            android:id="@+id/event_record_sort_switch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="@string/sort"
            android:tooltipText="@string/tooltip_sort"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/predict_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/predict_button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/predict_button" />
...
```

However a `NPE` would happen right after getting into that activity:

```
2023-03-23 15:21:36.630 17706-17706/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.omnieyes.omnilite, PID: 17706
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
        at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:455)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat.makeLayout(SwitchCompat.java:982)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat.onMeasure(SwitchCompat.java:905)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:811)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:466)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:134)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:278)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1594)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1708)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1412)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:452)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:747)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3397)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2228)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2486)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I do this because I want to apply a click-like tooltip with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66598648/7587958), which does `perfromLongClick()` in a `OnClickListener`. I'm trying to alter his way a little bit. I planned to do it inside its `init{}` block like this:

```
init {
        // so we can click and show its tooltip; a long-click still does
        setOnClickListener { performLongClick() }
    }
```

Which works with a class that extends `TextView`. Please help, thanks.

I have listed what I've tried up there. And I can't find any post or tutorial related that extends `SwitchMaterial`. Maybe there's no need to do this?

#### Edit: add build.gradle file

My `build.gradle` file would be like:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation project(path: ':opencv')
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    implementation group: 'org.javatuples', name: 'javatuples', version: '1.2'
    implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3')
    implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.5')
    implementation files('libs/openCVLibrary330-v1.1-release.aar')

    //firebase, choose for kotlin and java or Both.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:18.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
}
```

Comment: [android.R.attr.switchStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#switchStyle) was added in API 21. Are you running on an earlier version?

Comment: @Cheticamp `minSdk 26` and `targetSdk 31` in `build.gradle`

Comment: And the API level of the device or emulator you are using when you see the crash?

Comment: @Cheticamp API level 30 Pixel 4 AVD

Comment: Something is going on with your attributes. My thought is that, somehow, the `textOn` or `textOff` attribute is set to null and maybe both. Take a closer look at your code to check out this idea. If you are still stuck, post your gradle file to reveal library versions you are using.

Comment: @Cheticamp edited with `build.gradle` file posted

Comment: At the end setteled for a class `TipTextView` that extends `AppCompatTextView` with `init{ 
setOnClickListener{ performClick() } }`. Happy and satisfied....

Answer (score 0):

These types of errors that occur within system/library code can be hard to track down.

I am only able to reproduce your error by either 1) forcing the `defStyleAttr` to zero, or, 2) forcing the `textOn` attribute in the layout file to null (`android:textOn="@null"`). This tells me that your are losing the attribute or modifying the style such that the `textOn` and, probably, `textOff` comes up null. You may be able to satisfy yourself that this is the source of the problem by setting `android:textOn="On"` and `android:textOff="Off"` in the XML layout. *(This is not the fix, however.)*

So, why do I say this? If we take the top program reference lines in the stack trace in reverse order, we can see the code that is involved in the crash.

```
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat.onMeasure(SwitchCompat.java:905)
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        ...
        if (mOnLayout == null) {
            mOnLayout = makeLayout(mTextOnTransformed); // Line 905
        }
        ...
    }

    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat.makeLayout(SwitchCompat.java:982)
    private Layout makeLayout(CharSequence transformedText) {
        return new StaticLayout(transformedText, mTextPaint,
                transformedText != null
                        ? (int) Math.ceil(Layout.getDesiredWidth(transformedText, mTextPaint)) : 0, // Line 982
                Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.f, 0, true);
    }



    at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:455)
            this(source, 0, source.length(), paint, width, align, // Line 455
         spacingmult, spacingadd, includepad);
```

If we set a breakpoint at line 455 of *StaticLayout.java*, we can see that `source` is null and that leads directly to the crash.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference

Tracing back to the source of the `source` variable, we see that is comes from `mTextOnTransformed` (line 905 of `SwitchCompat.java`.) The only place where `mTextOnTransformed` is set is in the following code:

```
    In SwtichCompat.hava:
    private void setTextOnInternal(CharSequence textOn) {
        ...
        mTextOnTransformed = doTransformForOnOffText(textOn);
        ...
    }
```

And `textOn` is the text to display when the switch is "on" and it is null.

I can't tell you specifically how to correct this error, but take a close look at everything you have that touches the switch and its attributes including styles to try to identify what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your themes.xml file (or styles.xml)?

I had a similar issue, and after investigation, I found that my main app theme was extending Material 2 styles. My main app theme was like below:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    ...
</style>
```

After changing to extend Material 3 styles I was able to fix it.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: My main app's theme has `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`.